# Keeping track the filenames of images loaded into an Excel spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

It is quite easy to extract images from an Excel spreadsheet. For example, one can change the extension from xlsx to zip and go to a relevant subfolder.

However, the filenames therein are generic `image1.jpg`, `image2.jpg`, etc. Is there are a way to link these generic names with the original names (that is, names of these files before loading into the spreadsheet)?

Comment: have you reviewed the metadata to see if it is embedded there?

Answer (score 0):

Save as a web page (*.htm;*.html) instead. However, this will cause the images to be extracted using the resolution of the cell and not the source image.

So first change the size of all pictures quickly. press F5 and choose to select all objects. then in the picture tools all the way on the right choose a size for the width, let’s say 5″ or of your choice.

Comment: I am afraid the filenames are still generic after converting to html.