# Automatically producing names of images in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, automation

As described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1538583/keeping-track-the-filenames-of-images-loaded-into-an-excel-spreadsheet), Excel introduces generic filenames of images loaded into a spreadsheet. I wonder if it is possible to create a VBA script, or something else, that would book-keep these names in some place in the spreadsheet?

For example, to an empty spreadsheet I load `foo.jpg` and in some cell, I get `image1.jpg`. Then I load `bar.jpg` to get `image2.jpg` etc.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote but a feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write a VBA code like to one below to insert pictures and keep track of their names.

```
Sub InsertPicture()
    Dim sFileName As String


    sFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Pictures JPG (*.jpg)|*.jpg, Pictures PNG (*.png)|*.png", 0, "Select the Picture", , False)

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = sFileName

    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(sFileName).Select
End Sub
```